# Can not open include file : 'jni.h' no such file or directory

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

I am using windows SDK 7.1 command prompt to create dll from cpp. I am giving command

```
cl -I"C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\include"
-I"C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\include\win32" -MD -LD JNIExample.cpp -FeJNIExample.dll
```

But getting the error `Can not open include file : 'jni.h' no such file or directory.`

Is there any problem in giving path or there is need to give the full path of `.cpp` file also.
please help.

Comment: My Windows has a space between "Program" and "Files". Are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: initially I provided space between Program and Files , it was not working. can you suggest your full line of command which I may use for creating dll.

Comment: Your command line should work once you get the path right. Try typing `cl -I` only at first then navigate to your JDK folder in an Explorer window and drag the `include` directory to your command window. This will paste the correct path. Type a space and another `-I` and repeat for `win32` inside `include`. (If you're on a 64 bit Windows a 32 bit JDK will be in `Program Files (x86)`, dragging or copying from an explorer Window will get that right)

Comment: it worked. thanks a lot.